# Editing listview objects in fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I started using android studio and I am trying to create a list of students and their respective nationality with the ability to add/edit.
This is my class object Student

```
package com.example.simpleparadox.studentList;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class City implements Serializable{
private String Sname;
private String nationality;

City(String Sname, String nationality){
    this.Sname=name;
    this.nationality=nationality;
}

public void setName(String Sname) {
    this.Sname = Sname;
}

public void nationality(String nationality) {
    this.nationality = nationality;
}

String getSname() {
    return this.Sname;
}

String getNationality() {
    return this.nationality;
}}
```

This is the fragment to add/edit the student's name and nationality

```
public class AddStudentFragment extends DialogFragment {
private EditText sName;
private EditText nationlaity;
private OnFragmentInteractionListener listener;

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
void onOkPressed(City newCity);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context){
super.onAttach(context);
if(context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener){
    listener=(OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
}else{
    throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()+"must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
}}
static AddStudentFragment newInstance(Student student){
Bundle args=new Bundle();
args.putSerializable("student",student);
AddStudentFragment fragment=new AddStudentFragment();
fragment.setArguments(args);
return fragment;
}
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {//
//Inflate the layout for this fragment
View view= LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.add_city_fragment_layout,null);
sName=view.findViewById(R.id.student_name_editText);
nationality=view.findViewById(R.id.nationality_editText);

AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
return builder
        .setView(view)
        .setTitle("Add student")
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel",null)
        .setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface,int i){
                String newName=sName.getText().toString();
                String newNationality=nationality.getText().toString();
                listener.onOkPressed(new Student(newName,newNationality));
            }
        }).create();

}}
```

My goal is to create a multi-functional button which can add a student if I just pressed the "add" button. But if I select an item from listview of students and then press the button, it should edit the existing student's name and nationality. I have succeed on creating the first function but i am stuck at the edit part. Specifically I dont know how to retrieve an existing Student Object from Bundle. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

1. You need define ID for Student.
2. In `OnFragmentInteractionListener` interface you need have 2 funtions `addStudent(Student student)` and `editStudent(Student student)`.
3. In `AddStudentFragment`, define `Student selectedStuden` variable

   - `onStart`, get Student from `Bundle` and set for `selectedStudent`. If null, it is when you `add` new `Student`. Otherwise, it is when you `edit` a `Student`.
   - onCreateDialog, if `selectedStudent != null` , set student's name and nationality to `TexView`.
   - `onClick` :

```
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface,int i){
                if seletedStuden == null{
                    String newName=sName.getText().toString();
                    String newNationality=nationality.getText().toString();
                    listener.addStudent(new Student(newName,newNationality));
                } else {
                    seletedStuden.setName(sName.getText().toString());
                    seletedStuden.setNationality(nationality.getText().toString())
                    listener.editStudent(seletedStuden);
                }
                
            }
```

4. Base on `Student ID` update to the `Student List`